# Easy way to modify numpy slice object?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

If I have a slice object defined for example like this: `s = np.s_[10:20, 30:40]`, are there easy ways to do basic operations / manipulations on this object, without having to manually access `s[0][0]` etc... to create new slices?

Example: is there a magic function to shift a slice by `(x,y)` to obtain `shifted(s, x, y) = np.s_[10+x:20+x, 30+y:40+y]`, or do I have to create my own functions to do all these basic things?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [319]: s=np.s_[10:20, 30:40]
In [320]: s
Out[320]: (slice(10, 20, None), slice(30, 40, None))
```

So the result is a tuple containing 2 `slice` objects.

```
In [322]: s[0].start
Out[322]: 10
In [324]: s[0].start=20
...
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

So a `slice` can be created, but the attributes can't be changed.  But that's no big deal.  Creating a slice isn't expensive.  It's not a big array or list.  It's just a simple object with a couple of attributes.

To expand it into a array, use something like `np.r_`:

```
In [325]: np.r_[s]
Out[325]: 
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39])
```

Or the `s` tuple can be used to index an array:

```
In [328]: arr = np.arange(30*50).reshape(30,50)
In [329]: arr[s]
Out[329]: 
array([[530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539],
       [580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589],
       [630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639],
       [680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689],
       [730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739],
       [780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789],
       [830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839],
       [880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889],
       [930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939],
       [980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989]])
```

which is the same as `arr[10:20, 30:40]`, a view of `arr`.  You can't modify (the range of) the view, but you can certainly make a new view with new slices.

### index_tricks.py

Code for `np.s_` from `np.lib.index_tricks.py`

```
class IndexExpression(object):
    """
    A nicer way to build up index tuples for arrays.
    ...
    """

    def __init__(self, maketuple):
        self.maketuple = maketuple

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if self.maketuple and not isinstance(item, tuple):
            return (item,)
        else:
            return item

index_exp = IndexExpression(maketuple=True)
s_ = IndexExpression(maketuple=False)
```

Basically it's just a way of capturing the tuple that the Python interpreter generates when it sees code like `x[0:3, :]`.  It converts it to `x.__getitem__(atuple)`.

```
In [334]: np.s_[:,3:3,[1,2,3]]
Out[334]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(3, 3, None), [1, 2, 3])
```

Commas separate tuple elements, and the `n:m:i` strings are converted to `slice` objects.  This pure Python; nothing special for `numpy`.  Except that most standard Python classes lists don't work with a tuple index.

```
In [336]: list(range(10))[np.s_[2:5]]
Out[336]: [2, 3, 4]
```

In the same `index_tricks` file look at classes `AxisConcatenator` and `nd_grid` for more complex handling of the `key` argument given to `__getitem__`.

Comment: So the best I can do would be something like `def shift(s,offsets): for si, i in zip(s, offsets): s.start += i; s.end += i `?

Comment: Did you try it?  `+=` still gives me the `readonly` error.  But why do you want to  modify this tuple?

Comment: No didn't try ;). And dang, actually read your answer a bit too fast, missed the AttributeError thing! So basically the answer is "no", there is no easy way / magic function already existing.

Comment: Look at the `np.lib.index_tricks.py` file for more info on how `s_` works, and how you can perform even fancier stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The python `slice` object has no associated methods, and `numpy` seems to just re-use that class without modification (albeit with a new constructor `s_`).  So, it seems the answer is no.

If you really want to use slices, you'll need to write your own function like so:

```
def shifted(s, x, y):
    return np.s_[s[0].start + x: s[0].stop + x, s[1].start + y: s[1].stop + y]
```

Then you can just reassign:

```
 s = shifted(s, x, y)
```

Or you can make a subclass of `slice` and implement them as methods for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using slices you could just do a mesh of coordinates:

```
s = tuple(np.mgrid[10:20, 30:40])
```

`s` can then be called like a `slice` but manipulated like an `array`

```
arr[s]   # using hpaulj's test data
Out[]: 
array([[530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539],
       [580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589],
       [630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639],
       [680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689],
       [730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739],
       [780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789],
       [830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839],
       [880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889],
       [930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939],
       [980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989]])

def shifted(s, x, y):
    return (s[0] + x, s[1] + y)

arr[shifted(s,10,10)]
Out[]: 
array([[1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049],
       [1090, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1094, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099],
       [1140, 1141, 1142, 1143, 1144, 1145, 1146, 1147, 1148, 1149],
       [1190, 1191, 1192, 1193, 1194, 1195, 1196, 1197, 1198, 1199],
       [1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249],
       [1290, 1291, 1292, 1293, 1294, 1295, 1296, 1297, 1298, 1299],
       [1340, 1341, 1342, 1343, 1344, 1345, 1346, 1347, 1348, 1349],
       [1390, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1394, 1395, 1396, 1397, 1398, 1399],
       [1440, 1441, 1442, 1443, 1444, 1445, 1446, 1447, 1448, 1449],
       [1490, 1491, 1492, 1493, 1494, 1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1499]])
```

Beware that this will take up a lot more memory than a slice though

Comment: I do want to work with slices / views though... not only for memory efficiency but also because I'm modifying arrays in place.

Comment: Slices are read-only objects though, so operations/manipulations are by definition impossible without creating new slices

Comment: creating a new slice object (rather than modifying an existing one) isn't really a problem, all I'd like to know is whether I need to create all my modifying functions myself or if there are some existing ones hidden somewhere...